# How to keep div from shrinking, while others grow and shrink in flexbox

Tags: html, css

So I have one div with a set width of 225px(panel). The others are percentage based and use flexbox. The problem is the set width is decreasing in size as well. How would I avoid that , while keeping the same look?

LINK- https://jsfiddle.net/dr9ncLn0/10/

```
.panel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 225px;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  outline: solid red 1px
}
```

Comment: flex-shrink:0 to avoid shrinking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent shrinking you can use flex-shrink: 0, Info: [MDN flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)

```
.panel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 225px;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  outline: solid red 1px
  flex-shrink: 0
}
```